# Navigation Control Web browser control in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

MS Access 2016 form has WebBrowser Control showing a particular directory on our server. The window shows the directory fine, and you can click into sub folders, however there is no control to go back up the directory tree.

Most of the info I've found doesn't seem to work, including;

`Me.FilesWindow.GoBack`

I always get a "Method or data member not found" error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, that method would be used to manipulate an IE automation object, not the Access WebBrowser control. Article shows how to open IE object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx

Comment: agreed.  can't seem to find anything regarding file folder tree navigation